# Cloud Vision Product Search python API for creating a product set resource can't return processing result

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I try to use the Python API to use bulk import to create a product set with products; However, it will block at "Processing operation name".

About 1 hour later, the API still block at "Processing operation name". I double-check with the existing product set using COMMAND-LINE method. And the product set is successfully built.

I think something wrong in # synchronous check of operation status. 
I use sample code from https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/create-product-set#product-search-bulk-import-python:

```py
def import_product_sets(project_id, location, gcs_uri):
    """Import images of different products in the product set.
    Args:
        project_id: Id of the project.
        location: A compute region name.
        gcs_uri: Google Cloud Storage URI.
            Target files must be in Product Search CSV format.
    """
    client = vision.ProductSearchClient()

    # A resource that represents Google Cloud Platform location.
    location_path = client.location_path(
        project=project_id, location=location)

    # Set the input configuration along with Google Cloud Storage URI
    gcs_source = vision.types.ImportProductSetsGcsSource(
        csv_file_uri=gcs_uri)
    input_config = vision.types.ImportProductSetsInputConfig(
        gcs_source=gcs_source)

    # Import the product sets from the input URI.
    response = client.import_product_sets(
        parent=location_path, input_config=input_config)

    print('Processing operation name: {}'.format(response.operation.name))
    # synchronous check of operation status
    result = response.result()
    print('Processing done.')

    for i, status in enumerate(result.statuses):
        print('Status of processing line {} of the csv: {}'.format(
            i, status))
        # Check the status of reference image
        # `0` is the code for OK in google.rpc.Code.
        if status.code == 0:
            reference_image = result.reference_images[i]
            print(reference_image)
        else:
            print('Status code not OK: {}'.format(status.message))
```

I am looking for Python API designer to fix this processing error. And here is an error.

Comment: I think the API block at:
```python
# synchronous check of operation status
    result = response.result()
    print('Processing done.')
```

Comment: The current way to this API is comment:
```python
    #result = response.result()
    #print('Processing done.')

    #for i, status in enumerate(result.statuses):
       # print('Status of processing line {} of the csv: {}'.format(
         #   i, status))
        # Check the status of reference image
        # `0` is the code for OK in google.rpc.Code.
        #if status.code == 0:
         #   reference_image = result.reference_images[i]
           # print(reference_image)
       # else:
          #  print('Status code not OK: {}'.format(status.message))
```

Comment: Anyone who has the same problem can use this way to solve this problem. And you can use COMMAND-LINE method to check product set creating status.

Answer (score 0):

[ImportProductSets](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.productSets/import) is a long-running operation. The sample code blocks until the operation has completed. That is why the code looks like it is stuck. Since it is an async method, you could set up a callback instead if you wanted.

How many lines are in your csv file? You could try with a small file first to test.

Comment: My csv file includes 20,000 lines, which is the max value setting for ImportProductSets.             The reason why I point our the code looks like it is stuck is that I use both REST API and Python API to do the same thing. When REST API finish building the Product Set, the Python API still in the processing. I am not sure Python API is work in this situation. Thanks @Brendan